# SQL Ordering in a 1 - N - 1 relationship

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a SQLite DB with two tables:

**A**
PK | Name

**B**
PK | FK1 | FK2

in table B, both FK1 and FK2 reference the PK on table A (only one is actually set up as a foreign key on the DB, but the values in FK2 are still taken from the set of all PK's for table A).

The purpose of table B is to allow for non-linear orderings.  This holds 'next' relationships.  For example:

**A**
PK | Name

1 | First
2 | Second
3 | Third

**B**
PK | FK1 | FK2

1 | 1 | 2
2 | 2 | 3

This represents a linear flow from First -> Second -> Third.

I am looking for the best way to order the results from A.  Optimally, linear flows would be generated in the order specified by table B.  Non-linear flows would be slightly different, but for the most part should be ordered the same way (except for parallel paths being placed next to each other).

I've fooled around with every join I can think of, and SQLite does not support PL/SQL which is making this problem significantly more difficult.  Currently, I'm simply running:

```
A left join B on A.PK = B.FK1 order by B.FK2.
```

Whats the optimal way to join these tables and order the results?

Comment: what order do you want them in?

Comment: I'd like them to be listed as close as possible to the ordering described by the FK1 and FK2 columns in table B (obviously in some cases this won't be possible)

Comment: I think the syntax you need is `with recursive`.  This should allow you to select any starting point and walk the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE list AS (
  SELECT PK, Name
  FROM A
  WHERE PK = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A.PK, A.Name
  FROM list
  JOIN B ON list.PK = B.FK1
  JOIN A ON B.FK2 = A.PK
)
SELECT * FROM list;
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, thank you! The where clause in the first select statement (where pk = 1) was only allowing it to return a single record (the one with id = 1), however

Comment: You are correct sir, I need to figure out why it's not working with the full data.  Marking your answer as correct.  Thank you!